Determine if an element is scrollable
I'm looking for a way to determine if an element is scrollable in given direction. That is, if I can call Element.scrollBy to scroll it.
I've searched around extensively and ended up with:
/**
 * Whether the element can be scrolled.
 * @param {HTMLElement} el The element.
 * @param {boolean} vertical Whether the scroll is vertical.
 * @param {boolean} plus Whether the scroll is positive (down or right).
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the element can be scrolled.
 */
function canScroll(el, vertical = true, plus = true) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    const overflow = vertical ? style.overflowY : style.overflowX;
    const scrollSize = vertical ? el.scrollHeight : el.scrollWidth;
    const clientSize = vertical ? el.clientHeight : el.clientWidth;
    const scrollPos = vertical ? el.scrollTop : el.scrollLeft;
    const isScrollable = scrollSize > clientSize;
    const canScrollFurther = plus
        ? scrollPos + clientSize < scrollSize
        : scrollPos > 0;
    return (
        isScrollable &&
        canScrollFurther &&
        !overflow.includes("visible") &&
        !overflow.includes("hidden")
    );
}

The snippet works quite well on most occasions, but unfortunately not all occasions. Here is an example on CodePen where it is called on document.body, and document.body.clientHeight !== document.body.scrollHeight. In this case, it returned true, while it should return false, since calling document.body.scrollBy({top: 100}) doesn't yield any result.
How can I improve this canScroll function, so that it can correctly handle the given example?

"In this case, it returned true, while it should return false, since calling document.body.scrollBy({top: 100}) doesn't yield any result." - but document.documentElement.scrollBy(...) does. You're dealing with how browsers handle the "main" viewport scroll here, historically there has always been some "intertwining" between the html and body elements in that regard.

after the condition, you always return false; when you should do else return false; as alternative if the condition is not true.

I've edited the code so as to remove the unnecessary if-else.

As you discovered, checking if clientHeight is less than scrollHeight is not always reliable. I think the best way is to first check if the current scroll position is not 0, if it is, the element is scrollable. Otherwise you can try scrolling by 1 px, check offset again and revert to 0. This should not cause any visible movement as it all happens in a single frame.
Here is a working example.
// axis is one of "x" or "y", or if omitted, will check both
const isScrollable = (element, axis) => {
  if (!axis) {
    return isScrollable(element, "x") || isScrollable(element, "y");
  }

  const offset = axis === "x" ? "Left" : "Top";

  // Checking if clientHeight < scrollHeight is not always reliable
  if (element[`scroll${offset}`]) {
    return true;
  }

  element[`scroll${offset}`] = 1;
  const canScroll = element[`scroll${offset}`] > 0;
  element[`scroll${offset}`] = 0;
  return canScroll;
};


I've come up with a rather hacky solution. The main idea is to try to scroll, and detect whether the scroll has been successful:
/**
 * Detect whether the element can be scrolled using a hacky detection method.
 * @param {HTMLElement} el The element.
 * @param {boolean} vertical Whether the scroll is vertical.
 * @param {boolean} plus Whether the scroll is positive (down or right).
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the element can be scrolled.
 */
function hackyDetect(el, vertical = true, plus = true) {
    const attrs = vertical ? ["top", "scrollTop"] : ["left", "scrollLeft"];
    const delta = plus ? 1 : -1;
    const before = el[attrs[1]]; // Determine `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` before trying to scroll
    el.scrollBy({ [attrs[0]]: delta, behavior: "instant" }); // Try to scroll in the specified direction
    const after = el[attrs[1]]; // Determine `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` after we've scrolled
    if (before === after) return false;
    else {
        el.scrollBy({ [attrs[0]]: -delta, behavior: "instant" }); // Scroll back if applicable
        return true;
    }
}

Full demo available at the original CodePen. The drawback is that it'll interrupt ongoing scroll on el if it is scrollable, and might be less efficient, so I think it might be better to combine both methods: canScroll(...) && hackyDetect(...).

Ha, you beat me by 17 seconds. I just posted a similar approach (but without the option to check direction as well). This is perfectly fine and most reliable. If you first check whether the current scroll offset is !== 0 and return true in that case, it won't interrupt an ongoing scroll.

Haha, what a coincidence! In fact, I've been thinking of this method since yesterday, but just can't make up my mind to post it, since it seems too hacky for me.
